# Fast reports - bulleted text

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Is there a way you can have bulleted tekst in fast reports 4.13 ? I have a memo field which I would like to display bulleted. If not in fast reports are there any other delphi components that can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RichText` object (`TfrxRichView`) supports bulleted text.

[image]

The question which may naturally raise up, is how to make that bulleted list from code. Well, that's quite easy. You just set the `Numbering` property of the current `Paragraph` for the inner `RichEdit` of the `TfrxRichView` object to `nsBullet`. Assuming you have a `RichText` object named `Rich1` placed on a report `frxReport1`, you can use a code like this to make three bulleted items:

```
uses
  frxClass, frxRich, frxRichEdit;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Component: TfrxComponent;
begin
  Component := frxReport1.FindObject('Rich1');
  if Component is TfrxRichView then
  begin
    TfrxRichView(Component).RichEdit.Clear;
    TfrxRichView(Component).RichEdit.Paragraph.Numbering := nsBullet;

    TfrxRichView(Component).RichEdit.Lines.Add('Item 1');
    TfrxRichView(Component).RichEdit.Lines.Add('Item 2');
    TfrxRichView(Component).RichEdit.Lines.Add('Item 3');

    frxReport1.ShowReport;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are a life savior - Thank you!